# Read AWS S3 CSV Column Names in Lambda

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to write a script that collects the schema from an AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL database table, collects the column headers from a CSV file stored in an AWS S3 bucket, and only writes the CSV to the table if its column headers are a subset of the schema (e.g., if the table fields are ['Name', 'DOB', 'Height'] but the CSV fields are ['Name', 'DOB', 'Weight'] the script will throw an exception.

Thus far, I have successfully returned the table schema in an AWS Lambda function, and successfully read in the CSV file, but I am not sure how to get the column headers from the S3 object.

```
def return_db_schema(event):
    schema = []
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('SHOW columns FROM SampleTable')
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        for row in cur:
            schema.append(list(row)[0])
        return schema

def return_csv_cols(event):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    tester = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=test_key)
    contents = tester['Body'].read()

def main(event, context):
    print(return_db_schema(event))
    print()
    print(return_csv_cols(event))
```

I am unsure how to proceed from here (e.g., is there a way to do this without loading the CSV to a pandas DataFrame and calling `df.columns()` or something like that?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this with the following code:

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    tester = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=test_key)
    contents = tester['Body'].read().decode('UTF-8')
    cols = contents.split('\n')[0].split(',')
    return cols, contents
```

Comment: thank you this is helpful. cols is list of columns.
to check if column present then use in with list.

Answer (score 2):

(As you're using aws lambda) I think the best way is :

```
import csv
csv_file = s3.get_object(Bucket="s3_bucket", Key="test_key")
read_csv = csv_file["Body"].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(True) 
csv_data = csv.DictReader(read_csv)
```

Yes, **csv** library is available in lambda. Make sure you don't skip `decode` as it is use to decode the bytestream.

Now you can loop on `csv_data` and access using keys.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

After you open your cursor, you should be able to see the following

```py
my_columns_names = cursor.description
```

Also few suggestions,

1. You dont need to do `cur.close()` since you are opening a it using `with` context manager.
2. You can add code to close the db connection (`conn`).

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-description.html

Comment: I already have the table schema as a list (e.g., ['Name', 'DOB', 'Height']), but I'm having trouble getting the column names from the CSV file that I've loaded in ```return_csv_cols```.

Comment: oh! Please check, if the column names are already there in csv.  If the columns are there, you need to open that csv like a file & get columns names
```
with open('my.csv') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        return line.slipt(',')
````